# Debugging a intermittent bug by inducing failure and then fixing that induced failure: what's it called?

Tags: terminology

I just "fixed" an intermittent failure by this process:

1. Observe intermittent failure
2. Debug code; at one point near where the failure could be, pause execution, and inflict harm upon a variable (by, say, setting it to null)
3. Failure occurs
4. Fix the failure you just inflicted
5. Declare success

It's related to voodoo debugging and shotgun debugging, but I'm slightly more deliberate about it and I can at least prove that I fixed *something*. **What is this debugging technique called?**

(I'm thinking of calling it Debugging by Patent Medicine - step 6 would be "collect money from credulous peasants and swiftly move on to the next town.")

Comment: Black magic debugging. ...Voodoo doll optional.

Comment: Or perhaps "papering over the problem" would be appropriate as, if you haven't identified the root cause, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: I'm with Robert Harvey here. You haven't fixed anything, you've simply treated a symptom without curing the disease. If anything, you've just made your intermittent issue even harder to find and fix.

Comment: The code is a jobs-runner that has 4 threads finding and executing jobs. The bug was that some of those threads were... simply disappearing. The fix I applied was a try-catch block to find and log exceptions, *and then continue looping to pick up more jobs*. The bug's probably fixed at this point (threads are unlikely to die, though individual jobs can fail, and that's fine), but I can't prove it. So yes, if I didn't fix the bug, it's better-hidden now.